# Logging with pynput only every x seconds

Tags: python, logging, listener, delay, pynput

I want to use pynput in 2.7 to check for interactions with either the keyboard or the mouse. Since it's not about the actual data (like the keys) I want to keep it simple and check only every x seconds if there is a new input. If there has been one, then the timecode should be logged, if not the script needs to wait for the next input (whenever this may be).

I want to run this script all day long in order to check how much time is spend in which application.

So far I got it together, but the script logs up to 50-60 events per second. Faaaaaar to much data. So, I need to make it wait somehow.

I guess the decisive part of the script is the listener.

```
With MouseListener(on_move=on_move) as listener:
    With KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
         listener.join()
```

How can I alter this part to make it wait after joining?

Adding a time.sleep(5) didn't make a difference. Putting the 5 in the join() brackets (join(5)) as an outtime didn't work either.

Or would I need to make it wait in the

```
def on_press(key):
     # log the timecode
```

part for instance?

Hope there's an easy solution.

Cheers
Tom

Comment: Since a listener callback function runs in the same thread as the listener, that seems like it might be a good place where to put a timed delay (via `time.sleep()`).

Comment: Hi, Martin. Thx for the quick respond. Since I'm not a coder, I'm not sure that I can follow you exactly where to add the time.sleep(). Could you specify it please? Cheers!

P.S.: In case you mean in the on_press() function, there are also an on_move() and on_click() function. Somehow they should know to wait too, if the other got triggered. In this case, would I need to add a global variable with the time code for the next earliest execution? Each function could look it up and compare it to the current time and decide whether to execute or not. But probably this is very expensive for cpu.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you put the delay in the `on_press()` callback function because doing that ought to slow the whole listener thread down. I think you only need to slow down one thing in the listener thread.

Comment: In a way it works. It actualy only logs every 2s (with time.sleep(2)) in on_press, but the mouse is lagging as if the PC would be close to crashing. Funnily the task manager doesn't show any CPU usage. Any idea how to avoid it? Probably the listener still opens a lot of call back scripts which then slow everything down.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of the timed delay, you might be able to keep track of the last time you logged an event and then not do another until some minimum amount of time has elapsed.

Comment: Good point. While try to figure something out. Thx!

Comment: You can subtract the current and previous times and compare the differencet to `1 / max_samples_per_second` — i.e. 60 samples per sec → `0.01667`

Comment: O.k., found some time yesterday. I've put the "With MouseListener...." part into a function (def runListener ():). 
In the callback apart from the logging part I put in "return False". This stops the listener.
After listener.join() I placed  "time.sleep(5)" and in the next row the listener starts itself by calling runListener(). I just need to figure out how to combine the Mouse and the Keyboard now. The time.sleep() part could be relplaced with a check for a certain time or time interval. THx!